# Are the tags the best way to get more views?

Tags: discussion, tags, views

I asked a question [here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/881767/oraoledb-oracle-is-not-being-showed-in-provider-list-for-ssms) 2 days ago, but it only has 5 views.  I read in other questions on meta.stackexchange.com where providing more tags can result in greater exposure.  Is this true and what is the typical limit on how many tags you should use?

Normally in StackOverflow, it takes a couple of hours to get answers or comments.  It this time frame similar across other popular Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: I don't know much about Server Fault, so I can't comment about how popular certain tags are there or how quickly those questions get responses, but a big point to keep in mind: Stack Overflow gets _much_ more traffic in a day than any of the other sites. That means more chances for someone who sees your post to be able to at least comment on it, though it also means your post gets bumped off the front page faster... Just a difference to keep in mind.

Comment: @Kendra yes, it also seems there is more traffic during the weekdays that weekends.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, tags can help you get views, but be careful, and don't abuse them.

If your question can **appropriately** have many tags, it may get more views. People can set up alerts on tags and be notified when someone asks a question with a certain tag. It follows that more tags may equal more people being notified, which may lead to more views. There are also people, like me, who regularly browse certain tag feeds looking for interesting questions.

However, it should be noted that one of the fastest ways of getting downvoted into oblivion is to "spam" unnecessary tags. If you tag something with "C" for example, but your question is really about C++, you can bet the person being notified about a C question isn't going to be very happy when they find out that you're just wasting their time.

Tag everything that's appropriate to help your question reach the right audience. Do *not* abuse tags though, or the attention you get won't be good attention.